# Can I transfer money from my Deferred Compensation Plan to buy Bitcoin?

Tags: exchanges

I have money in a Deferred Comp plan and want to use it to buy Bitcoin.

Comment: You can use money to buy Bitcoin by using a Bitcoin exchange. I don't know what a DCP is, but what you can use that money for is not a question relating to Bitcoin, so I'm voting to close this.

Comment: That sounds like something only the manager/organizer of your DCP would be able to answer or arrange, so as @HighlyIrregular said this is off-topic here I'm afraid

Answer (score 1):

You *can*, but maybe you shouldn't.

Don't buy Bitcoin using money that you can't afford to lose.